# Mercurial - possible to do restrictions?

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial

I'm looking into using Mercurial (I've had enough of SVN merge). Is it possible to have a repo wherein individuals are restricted to what they have access to? For example, a frontend developer would only have access to HTML and CSS files, etc.

I guess I am looking for something like: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to distributed nature of Mercurial it is not possible to do. User either has read permissions to the whole repository, or not.

About writes: it is possible to control this on server side with hooks though, but in this case it will be a big headache for developers who made changes by accident or had to do them and got blocked because of lack of permissions to push (thus continue working)

Comment: How about several repos where each person gets access to just the repos relevant to their work? Then a "main" repo that combines them all? Sounds messy.

Comment: Yes it does. But why do you need it? We have several dozens of developers working in a repo. And each one does just his own job. Any reason to strictly deny something?

Comment: And as I said - it is possible to deny to write some specific dirs/files by using server-side hook (that will be triggered on push), but from my own experience it will be more evil, than good.

Answer (score 0):

- [ACL extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AclExtension) can help
- You can also  split repo on separate repos and join parts into big project with [subrepos](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) (or just have more than one repo in paths and perform pulls from all)

Comment: ACL will help only on push stage. It will not help in cloned copies. And it requires specific settings of mercurial sharing scheme

Comment: zerkms, what do you think about the split repo idea?

Comment: @zerkms - RTFM **it can restrict changes depending on its source (http, ssh, pull, push, bundle).**

Comment: @Lazy Badger: I know that, and I was talking about another thing

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: Even though it would work - I don't see reason to make things more complex than it is necessary. I work in several big projects (dozens of developers, several dozens of thousands of changesets) and we don't experience any issues with it.

Comment: @zerkkms - trying to protect intellectual property over a globally distributed team. This shouldn't be so hard.